# Is it possible to change content of router-outlet tag in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I'd like to implement a drill-down dashboard by the following route in Angular 7.

The app works like the following:

- navigate to the url: http://localhost:4200/version where the available versions of a given software are displayed with extra information. It is called **versions** page
- by selecting a version on **versions** page the content of the versions page should be swapped to **version-detail** page. This way the user can drill-down and see further details of the selected component http://localhost:4200/versions/(version_detail:1.2)

For achieving describing above

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/info', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent },
    {
        path: 'versions',
        component: VersionComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':version',
                component: VersionDetailComponent,
                outlet: 'version_detail'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The VersionComponent html looks like the following:

```
<router-outlet name="version_distribution">
    <div style="padding:10px; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; max-width: 90%; max-width: 90%;">
        <p-chart type="bar" [data]="data" width="75vw" height="75vh" (onDataSelect)="onDataSelect($event)"></p-chart>
    </div>
</router-outlet>
```

As a result the content of the page does not change when I select a version. However, if the content looks like below the routing works and the version details will be loaded at the top of the page:

```
<router-outlet name="version_distribution"></router-outlet>
    <div style="padding:10px; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; max-width: 90%; max-width: 90%;">
        <p-chart type="bar" [data]="data" width="75vw" height="75vh" (onDataSelect)="onDataSelect($event)"></p-chart>
    </div>
```

Question is that, how is possible to swap content during routing? I had the assumption the content included in `<router-outlet>` tags are swapped.

I'm thinking about a possible workaround where the versions page, as landing page of this section of the app, is also loaded by child route so the whole logic is managed as child routes. But, I'm curious whether possible to solve this case whith my original approach.

Comment: No, content underneath outlets are swapped. You're not supposed to put anything in the router outlet tag. Also, putting code in the same template as the router will not swap it, as the router is only a placeholder for routed content.

Answer (score -2):

Router-Outlet is content place holder which will display the selected version from versions.
ex: From the below versions

```
1.Version1 
2.Version2
3.Version3

<Router-Outlet>"Here Version information will be displayed."</Router-Outlet>
```

On Click of Version1, router outlet will display Version1 information in DOM, and not Version2 and Version3.

For navigation you should use: `route.navigate(/versions/(version_detail:1.2))` for every specific version you are using.